# How do I use SESSION data to SELECT 1 database entry and then INSERT into another table with data from a form as well with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

All security issues aside.

- I have created some session data. This session data includes a
  username stored under "myusername".
- I have also created an html form that adds a row to one of my
  tables.

---

I am trying to get some data retrieved from a query (using the session data) to be put in with the form data that has been submitted.

Essentially create a record of who submitted the data.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){
  header("location:failedlogin.html");
}
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
var_dump($_SESSION);

//Connect
$con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("database1", $con);

//create Get UserId from user
$result= mysql_query("SELECT UserId FROM user
WHERE UserName='{$_SESSION['myusername']}'");

//I think this is where the problem is 
//execute query and store results
if($result){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

//insert form data and $data into database 1
$sql="INSERT INTO bug 
(bugName, bugBy, bugPriority, bugFor, bugContainer, bugFixed, bugCommentCount)
VALUES ('$_POST[bugname]','$data[0]','$_POST[bugpriority]',
        '$_POST[bugfor]','$_POST[bugcontainer]','0','0')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_close($con)
?>
```

I can't seem to get get it to submit the data from the `SELECT` query, the form data goes through fine.

Sorry if I've laid this out terribly. I'm finding it hard to understand what I've done wrong, so I don't know how to explain what I'm looking for very well.

Thanks for any and all help! Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: mysql_close($con) should be mysql_close($con); (last line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL statement is incorrect, the variables require escaping.

```
"...VALUES('". $_POST['bugname'] . "')";
```

As you currently have it `$_POST[bugname]` will try to find a *constant* global variable called 'bugname'. This will not exist.

However, `$_POST['bugname']` will reference the correct key within the array.

I have to mention that this is not only a terrible way to create a SQL statement, It is also [very insecure](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: I'm now getting `Notice: Use of undefined constant bugname - assumed 'bugname' in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\bugs\onsubmit.php on line 33`. It's totally working though, so should I just not worry about it? I will look through the link you gave me and screw it, it says not to, but thankyou so much!

Comment: @Cash Make sure you are using the `$_POST['bugname']` rather than  `$_POST[bugname]` in all places.

Answer (score 0):

You're using fetch_assoc, so it's returning an associative array:

instead of `$data[0]`

insert `$data['UserId']`

If that doesn't do it, have you check to see if `$data` has anything before your insert statement?

p.s. you should learn PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: The combination of this and AlexP's post got it working, I'm still getting some notices though `Notice: Use of undefined constant bugname - assumed 'bugname' in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\bugs\onsubmit.php on line 33` don't know if it matters or not really. And although it says not to, thankyou so much!

Comment: good to hear. I think AlexP tipped you off on that. Good luck!